# Hide Auth section in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, authentication

In the Django Admin, is there any way to hide the "Auth" section?  Assuming this is a clean installation of Django and barebones project with no apps, only admin.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use `admin.site.unregister`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.unregister(Site)
```

Comment: another side-question is where to put that code ?

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande Usually, you'd have an `admin.py` file in you apps package. But it is also possible to add it to the `models.py` file

Comment: A good place to put this code is the admin.py of the app you create to override the Django User, if exists.