# How to disable authentication altogether for Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postgis

I have a Django server (Using PostGis) and I want to disable everything related to authentication:

- When entering the admin no authentication will be required
- In the admin hide the Users/Groups

After searching online I tried the combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008282/5019818)  & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5508920/5019818)

It does get me the result I hoped for, until I try to add an object via the admin. Then I get an `IntegrityError`:

```
insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user".
```

I tried solving it using solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34109293/5019818) and it didn't help.

I don't mind having a solution in a whole new approach as long as the end goal is acquired.

Thanks ahead,

Comment: You need to actually create a User with id=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Django project is running in dockers, and can be deployed when the users already exist or don't I ended up doing:

```
# Create superuser for admin use in case it doesn't exist
try:
    User.objects.get_by_natural_key('admin')
except User.DoesNotExist:
    User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@comapny.com', '123456')
```

Hope this helps someone one day. Full use:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group


# We add this so no authentication is needed when entering the admin site
class AccessUser(object):
    has_module_perms = has_perm = __getattr__ = lambda s,*a,**kw: True

admin.site.has_permission = lambda r: setattr(r, 'user', AccessUser()) or True

# We add this to remove the user/group admin in the admin site as there is no user authentication
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.unregister(Group)

# Create superuser for admin use in case it doesn't exist
try:
    User.objects.get_by_natural_key('admin')
except User.DoesNotExist:
    User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@optibus.co', '123456')
```