# How to add disable password for django users

Tags: django, python-3.4, django-authentication

I have created a tool for my colleagues and i have integrated SSO with this django application as well.

Now the way i'm planning to authenticate users are like the following.

1. SSO page is sending the logged in user ID in cookie.
2. If the logged in user have an account in django users, i'll check for a match and i should authenticate the user.

The challenge i'm facing here is while creating users i have to provide password and i don't want to validate user password again.

Is there a way i can disable the password while we add the user in to django admin itself?

I'm using Django 1.11 with python 3.4.

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable authentication altogether for Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141017/how-to-disable-authentication-altogether-for-django-admin)

Comment: But i don't want to remove auth for admin, i want to remove password field for users only.